# Errno 2 No such file or directory:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook (python 3.8 both from anaconda3) and following [this](https://github.com/ChilesheChanda/TwitterSentimentAnalysis/blob/master/SentimentAnalysis.ipynb) post, cells 84 and 85 are resulting in the traceback and followed the advice of

```
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-15-9cdebd0bb247> in <module>
    2 
    3 
----> 4 create_wordcloud(tw_list["text"].values)

    <ipython-input-14-524a73dcd1e0> in create_wordcloud(text)
    2 
    3 def create_wordcloud(text):
----> 4     mask = np.array(Image.open("cloud.png"))
    5     stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
    6     wc = WordCloud(background_color="white",

    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
    2889 
    2890     if filename:
 -> 2891         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
    2892         exclusive_fp = True
    2893 

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cloud.png'
```

following this i found advice (the link evades me but its somewhere on this site to change `from PIL import image` to `import PIL.image` in cell 2 and add

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='cloud.png')
```

still resulting in a similar, but longer traceback

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-16-8c5d56ae9874> in <module>
    1 #Creating wordcloud for all tweets
    2 from IPython.display import Image
 ----> 3 Image(filename='cloud.png')
    4 
    5 create_wordcloud(tw_list["text"].values)

    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py in 
    __init__(self, data, url, filename, format, embed, width, height, retina, 
    unconfined, metadata)
    1222         self.retina = retina
    1223         self.unconfined = unconfined
 -> 1224         super(Image, self).__init__(data=data, url=url, filename=filename, 
    1225                 metadata=metadata)
    1226 

    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py in 
    __init__(self, data, url, filename, metadata)
     628             self.metadata = {}
     629 
 --> 630         self.reload()
     631         self._check_data()
     632 

     ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py in 
     reload(self)
     1254         """Reload the raw data from file or URL."""
     1255         if self.embed:
    -> 1256             super(Image,self).reload()
     1257             if self.retina:
     1258                 self._retina_shape()

      ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py in 
      reload(self)
       653         """Reload the raw data from file or URL."""
       654         if self.filename is not None:
   --> 655             with open(self.filename, self._read_flags) as f:
       656                 self.data = f.read()
       657         elif self.url is not None:

        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cloud.png'
```

which evidently is not the right solution, I am a little out of my depth here and grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the file does not exist in the directory it is called. You must download their 'cloud.png' and put it in the same file as the jupyter notebook file.

https://github.com/ChilesheChanda/TwitterSentimentAnalysis/blob/master/cloud.png